# Prove that for any $c \in \mathbb{R}$, $\displaystyle \lim_{x\to c}{f(x)}$ does not exist.

Tags: real-analysis, limits

Let $f:\Bbb R\to \Bbb R$ be defined by
$$
f(x)=
\begin{cases}
1 & x\in\Bbb Q \\
0 & x\notin\Bbb Q
\end{cases}
$$
Prove that for any $c\in\Bbb R$, $\displaystyle\lim_{x\to c}f(x)$ does not exist.

I'm pretty stumped here. My first thought was to somehow find a contradiction for the definition of the limit? But I wasn't sure how to do so. Any help is appreciated!

Comment: rational and irrational are both dense on real axis.

Comment: Should'nt it be $c\in\Bbb Q$ ?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You will need to prove the following fact, from which everything else quickly follows:

Between any two real numbers $x$ and $z$, we can always find a $y_1 \in \mathbb{Q}$ and a $y_2 \in \mathbb{R} \setminus \mathbb{Q}$ such that $y_1, y_2 \in (x, z)$.  Once you have proven this, then we know any $\delta$ ball around a given $c \in \mathbb{R}$ contains both irrational and rational numbers.  So setting $\displaystyle \varepsilon$ equal to, say, $\displaystyle \frac{1}{2}$, problems arise!

Answer (score 0):

This answer is very abstract... but gets the job done.
Considering any rational number c, it will either have a finite decimal expansion, or a non-terminating but repeating expansion.

Therefore, If we examine $\lim_{x\to{c^+}} f(x)$ , we see x is just bigger than c... hence its expansion would be terminating and non-repeating, i.e, x is irrational.

Hence limit would not exist at real c.